# convert a varchar(14) to a datetime cause a exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, converters

I have a database where I have patients. A patient has an enter and an exit date witch were strings.

for example: `20130510183900 (10-05-2013 18:39)`
first the one in the database and then the value I need

I want to convert this to a datetime, so I can compare it with other dates.

I also can't show it converted in a view

I have already tried to convert it first in a varchar or in a int without any success

```
convert(datetime, enterDate, 121) -- does not work
convert(datetime, enterDate, 121) AS enterDate -- does not work
```

The error I get is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: `... so I can compare it with other dates` ← If you are only "comparing" (equals exactly, greater than, less than) to other values the existing string values would work as is. If you need to do any calculations on them (time span differences or adding months or comparing only a part of the date time) then you need to convert. That said you should always pick the appropriate data type when storing values.

Comment: im using microsoft sql server managment studio

Comment: Please always specify what version of SQL Server you are using (and if it's < 2012, please update to a supported version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is wrong to store datetime values as strings. Having said that, you can use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` function:

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    SUBSTRING(enterDate,  1, 4),
    SUBSTRING(enterDate,  5, 2),
    SUBSTRING(enterDate,  7, 2),
    SUBSTRING(enterDate,  9, 2),
    SUBSTRING(enterDate, 11, 2),
    SUBSTRING(enterDate, 13, 2),
    0
)
FROM (SELECT '20130510183900') AS v(enterDate)
```

Again, it is wrong to store datetime values as strings.

Comment: fist of all thank you for your quick responds and for the editing

Comment: but now i get this error 'DATETIMEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Nötter If you are using an unsupported version of SQL Server that doesn't have `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` then (a) why didn't you specify that as a tag on your question, and (b) why did you accept this answer?

Comment: @AaronBertrand to be fair, that error might also be raised even in 2019 version, since [it still supports compatibility level of 100](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017) (though I agree it's unlikely)...

Comment: @Zohar lowering compatibility level doesn't remove built-in scalar functions; it works just fine in 100 compat level. It can affect table-valued functions like `STRING_SPLIT()` but it has no impact on `*FROMPARTS()`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I believed you even before the image, even though I've read in an article it's a bad habit to believe everything you hear or read ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a combination of `stuff` and `convert`:

```
DECLARE @DateString varchar(14) = 20130510183900 

SELECT CONVERT(DateTime,
                STUFF(
                    STUFF(
                        STUFF(
                            STUFF(
                                STUFF(@DateString, 13, 0, ':')
                            , 11, 0, ':')
                        , 9, 0, 'T')
                    , 7, 0, '-')
                , 5, 0, '-'),
               126)
```

The `stuff` functions converts the string to `2013-05-10T18:39:00`
and the `convert` with 126 style changes it to a `DateTime` value.

But I agree with Salman - It's wrong to store datetime values as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DateString varchar(14) = '20130510183900'

-- desired format: '20130510 18:39:00'
SET @DateString = STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@DateString,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @DateString)
-- Output: 2013-05-10 18:39:00.000
```

Your problem was the input string, sql cannot handle this without adjusting the string. By the way: the 3rd parameter of Convert() is used to cast/format a datetime to a string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(datetime, @DateString), 101)
-- Output: 05/10/2013
```

Usage in a select:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(<DateTimeStringColumn>,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')) AS DateTimeValue
FROM ...
```

Comment: that would work but i have over 7000 data sets so should i use a substring?

Comment: @Nötter Can you define a "data set"? You have 7,000 tables, rows, columns, values within a blob column, ...? And why are your dates in this awful format in the first place? Can't you transform them into a sane format before they get to the database?

Comment: @Nötter: it is only a runable example, you don't need declare and set here.
if you want to use this in a select, try this


     SELECT CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(<DateTimeStringColumn>,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
FROM ...

Comment: and like @AaronBertrand wrotes: if you have the option to transform it before you insert it into the database it will be the better option!!!